# Wordpress QODE banner acting weird

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

We took over a Wordpress website. The website uses the Bridge theme, this theme uses QODE slider as banner plugin.

The problem is:
The banner is not visible on desktops it is only visible on the mobile lay out. When the page loads in the banner position is visible but when the loading is done, the banner pops away. We can fix it with some CSS hacks, but that’s not the right way. It is probably a setting in the plugin or the theme but we can't find it anywhere.

It also looks like a js file adds a negative margin of 1100px to content...
The css hack we used is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .header_bottom .container_inner {
        position: fixed !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        background-color: white !important;
        margin-top: -20px !important;
    }

    .container{
        position: relative !important;
    }

    .content{
        margin-top: 0 !important;
    }

    .q_slider_inner{
        padding-top: 20px !important;
    }

    .title_size_small{
        height: 0px !important;
    }


    .header_bottom .container_inner{
        margin-left: -45px !important;
    }

        .content .container .container_inner.page_container_inner{
        padding: 200px 0 0 0 !important;
    }
}
```

When the page is loading:
[image]

When the page stops loading:
[image]

When we used our css hack:
[image]

Does some of you have any experience with the bridge theme or the QODE plugin? or do you know how to find such issues is Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

We work exclusively with the Bridge theme when we're not creating custom WordPress websites for clients. There was a problem with the last version of Bridge and the Chrome 55 update. I think this might be the problem your experiencing. There is an update to Bridge that fixes the issue now, otherwise, you do have to use a CSS hack. You can see more info on this issue at

https://qode.ticksy.com/article/9535/

Comment: hmm doesn't do the trick. Thnx anyway. We optimised our own CSS hack and it work fine now. But it isn't the solution I was hoping for.